# check size of relation being build in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a loaded OLTP db. I `ALTER TABLE.. ADD PK` on 100GB relation - want to check the progress. But until it is built I haven't it in pg_catalog for other transactions, so can't just select it.

I tried `find ./base/14673648/ -ctime 1` also `-mtime` - hundreds of files, an dthen I thought - why do I think it has created a filenode?.. Just because it ate some space.

So forgive my ignorance and advise - how do I check the size on PK being created so far?

**Update**: I can sum `./base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmpPID.N`. where PID is pid of session that creats PK as [per docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html):

> Temporary files (for operations such as sorting more data than can fit
>   in memory) are created within PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp, or within a
>   pgsql_tmp subdirectory of a tablespace directory if a tablespace other
>   than pg_default is specified for them. The name of a temporary file
>   has the form pgsql_tmpPPP.NNN, where PPP is the PID of the owning
>   backend and NNN distinguishes different temporary files of that
>   backend.

**New question: How can I get it from pg_catalog?**

```
pondstats=# select pg_size_pretty(temp_bytes) from pg_stat_database where datid = 14673648;
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 89 GB
(1 row)
```

shows the sum of all temp files, not per relation

Comment: I think you can get a better help at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JorgeCampos I need more point to be able to migrate the question - right?..

Comment: You can ask it there directly. Just create an account.

Answer (score 1):

A primary key is implemented with a unique index, and that has files in the data directory.

Unfortunately there is no way to check the progress of index creation (unless you know your way around the source and attach to the backend with a debugger).

You only need to concentrate on relation files are do *not* in the output of

```
SELECT relfilenode FROM pg_class
   WHERE relfilenode <> 0
UNION
SELECT pg_relation_filenode(oid) FROM pg_class
   WHERE pg_relation_filenode(oid) IS NOT NULL;
```

Once you know which file belongs to your index-in-creation (it should be growing fast, unless there is a lock blocking the statement) you can start guessing how long it has to go by comparing it to files belonging to a comparable index on a comparable table.

All pretty hand-wavy, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah - I tried this as first option - the number of empty returns was too big. The amount of parallel DDL was too high. I grepped /base/DBOID, but still over 30 `pg_filenode_relation `were empty. I hoped I would find relation PID to temp_files, but failed. FS showed it OK though. Anyway - thank for the answer!